# Strange script font appearing in Google search results and Firebug

Tags: fonts, browser

The weirdest thing has just occurred. I did a google search and once the page had rendered I could see double f's had been replaced with a strange script font. Even weirder, once I chose to have a look using Firebug, the strange script font appeared there also. Why is this?

I've attached a picture of what I saw.[image]

P.S. The Search was for "[wget facebook](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=SUV&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&q=wget+facebook&aq=f&aqi=g1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=)"

Comment: I don't see a picture, but this sounds like something that should be asked over on SuperUser

Comment: Yeah, that is wierd. Try webmasters.stackexchange.com I doubt superusers can help on this one.

Comment: Is `[help]` really the best tag you could think of?

Comment: I'd guess the page source would show explicit ff and ffi ligatures (&#fb00; U+ffb0 pp), and if your font doesn't have them, it'll fall back on some other font. For me, it's something sans-serif for your search, you seem to get Zapfino.

Answer (score 2):

Pango is replacing instances of "ff and "ffi" with [ligatures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature), but the font you're using doesn't seem to have ligands so the font substitution engine is looking for one that does, and finding that fancy font first.

Comment: Whoops, didn't notice Ulrich's comment.